# We have a continuous function $f:\Bbb R→\Bbb R$ so that...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

We have a continuous function $f:\Bbb R→\Bbb R$ so that
$$\lim_{x→\pm∞}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=0$$
Prove that $∀m∈\Bbb R^+$ $∃c∈\Bbb R$ so that
$$mx^2+f(x)≥mc^2+f(c)$$
Can somebody tell me how to interpret (and how to solve) this? I tried constructing another function such as $h(x)=m+\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ but that wasn't of much use.

*EDIT this is supposed to hold $\forall x\in \Bbb R$

*EDIT 2 see limit

Comment: You are trying to show that for every choice of positive number $m$, the function $h_{m}(x):=mx^{2}+f(x)$ attains a global minimum.

Comment: Following on @SinisterCutlass's comment, you are missing a quantifier.  After $\exists c \in \Bbb R$ there should be $\forall x \in \Bbb R$  Now you have a sentence without free variables.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for making this comment, Ross.  I assumed that the issue was obvious and that the context was clear enough, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: Continuity aside, we only have information about $f(x)$  for large $x$.  I don't see how we are going to prove an inequality valid for *all* $x$.  My guess is the missing quantifier is $\forall x \geq c$.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed the missing quantifier and the limit was missing the $\pm$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $m\in \Bbb R^+$ and consider the function $g(x)=mx^2+f(x)$, then $g(x)$ has a global minimum in $\Bbb R$. To see this consider the limit
$$\lim_{ x \to \pm \infty} g(x)=\lim_{ x \to \pm \infty} mx^2+f(x)=\lim_{ x \to \pm \infty} x^2(m+\frac{f(x)}{x^2})= + \infty.$$
Since $g(x)$ is continuous, the previous limit implies that $g(x)$ must have at least one global minimum $c$. Such $c$ satisfies 
$$f(x)+mx^2\ge mc^2+f(c).$$